# How to integrate $\int\limits_{y = d}^\infty {\frac{{\exp \left( { - a \times y} \right)}}{{b \times y + c}}dy}$?

Tags: integration, special-functions

How to integrate $\int\limits_{y = d}^\infty  {\frac{{\exp \left( { - a \times y} \right)}}{{b \times y + c}}dy}$ (with respect to $y$) where $a,b,c,d>0$ or at least rewrite this integral as some form of special function such as bessel or Ei function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firt quickly note that if $a = 0$, we have a simple logartihm, which tends to infinity.

Apart from the trivial case, this problem is very familiar to an exponential integral, so we can try to reshape it to the form where we can use it. Consider
$$I(y) = \int \frac {e^{-ay}} {by + c}\,dy$$
Then we can make a variable change
$$ay + \frac{ac}{b} = t\implies y = \frac t a - \frac {c}{b} \implies dy = \frac{dt}{a}$$
$$I(t(y)) = \int \frac{e^{-t + \frac{ac}{b}}}{\frac{b}{a}t} dt = \frac{a}{b}e^{\frac{ac}{b}}\int \frac{-e^t}{t} dt$$

So
$$I(y=\infty) - I(y=d) = \frac{a}{b}e^{\frac{ac}{b}} Ei(t) = \frac{a}{b}e^{\frac{ac}{b}} Ei(ad + \frac{ac}{b})$$

Comment: I want to thank you for your answer, but how can you come up with the Ei integral ? I put this thing into Mathematica and it seems to just stuck there for a really long time.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand clearly what you mean here. As far as I know there is no closed form solution for the Ei function, however you can try to approximate it. One way to do that is to use a Taylor approximation.
$$e^{-t} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-t)^k}{k!}$$
$$\int e^{-t}/t dt =  \log t + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-t)^k}{k \cdot k!}$$

Comment: I just realized that I made a mistake in my answer in the Ei'sdefinition.I'm gonna correct it.

Comment: Thank you for your carefulness !